# How can we use the SAP could base url from Spartacus angular app in Stackblitz?

Tags: sap-cloud-platform, spartacus-storefront

How can we use the SAP could base URL from Spartacus angular app in https://stackblitz.com/ ?

How can we Configure backend URL (OCC) ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The documentation provides various ways to configure the [OCC base url](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/configuring-base-url/). Have you check this? It should not differ on stackblitz actually.